# Advanced bidirection jackson serialization to avoid infinite recusion

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jackson, spring-data

I have a Spring Data project which roughly has the entity setup which I show in a minimal implementation below to demonstrate my problem:

```
public class JacksonTest {
  @Test
  public void userWithRoles() throws JsonProcessingException {
    User u1 = new User();
    u1.setName("U1");

    Role r1 = new Role();
    r1.setName("R1");

    UserRole ur1 = new UserRole();
    ur1.setRole(r1);
    ur1.setUser(u1);
    ur1.setMetaData("metaData1");

    u1.setRoles(Collections.singletonList(ur1));
    r1.setUsers(Collections.singletonList(ur1));

    String result = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(u1);

    /*
    Expected result
    {
    name: U1,
    roles: [{metaData: metaData1, role: {name: R1}}]
    }
     */

  }

  @Test
  public void roleWithUsers() throws JsonProcessingException {
    User u1 = new User();
    u1.setName("U1");

    Role r1 = new Role();
    r1.setName("R1");

    UserRole ur1 = new UserRole();
    ur1.setRole(r1);
    ur1.setUser(u1);
    ur1.setMetaData("metaData1");

    u1.setRoles(Collections.singletonList(ur1));
    r1.setUsers(Collections.singletonList(ur1));

    String result = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(r1);

    /*
    Expected result
    {
    name: R1,
    users: [{metaData: metaData1, user: {name: U1}}]
    }
     */
  }
}

@Data
class UserRole {
  User user;
  Role role;
  String metaData;
}

@Data
class User {
  String name;
  List<UserRole> roles;
}

@Data
class Role {
  String name;
  List<UserRole> users;
}
```

Running either of the tests will result in an infinite recursion.

I have tried using `@JsonIgnore`, `@JsonManagedReference`, `@JsonBackReference` to solve my problem but non of them can make both tests green.

The main issue I have is that the serialization should give different versions of `UserRole` depending on if im serializing a `User` or a `Role` as demonstrated in the two tests.

My question is how I would make both the tests here to work with the expected output?

Comment: In both cases you are serializing the user, so why should it differentiate?

Comment: My bad, i have updated the example. The question is the same

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom `JsonSerializer`

- one for the `List<UserRole> roles` in `User` @see `UserUserRoleSerializer`
- and an other for the `List<UserRole> users` in `Role` @see `RoleUserRoleSerializer`

```java
@Data
class UserRole {
    User user;
    Role role;
    String metaData;
}

@Data
class User {
    String name;
    @JsonSerialize(using = UserUserRoleSerializer.class)
    List<UserRole> roles;
}

@Data
class Role {
    String name;
    @JsonSerialize(using = RoleUserRoleSerializer.class)
    List<UserRole> users;
}

class RoleUserRoleSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<UserRole>>  {

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<UserRole> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartArray();
        for (UserRole userRole : value) {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeObjectField("role", userRole.role.name);
            gen.writeObjectField("metadata", userRole.metaData);
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
        gen.writeEndArray();
    }
}

class UserUserRoleSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<UserRole>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<UserRole> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartArray();
        for (UserRole userRole : value) {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeObjectField("user", userRole.user.name);
            gen.writeObjectField("metadata", userRole.metaData);
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
        gen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

this will output:

userWithRoles: `{"name":"U1","roles":[{"user":"U1","metadata":"metaData1"}]}`

roleWithUsers: `{"name":"R1","users":[{"role":"R1","metadata":"metaData1"}]}`